# Why is the width attribute of a XUL button ignored?

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I have problems to set the width of my XUL button. I have this code:

```xml
<button label="Ok" width="16" maxwidth="16" height="16" maxheight="16"/>
```

By with that code, the size of my entire window is changed and not only the button.

And when I write that :

```xml
<button label="Ok" width="16" height="16"/>
```

Only the height is changed. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XUL uses the [flexible box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Tutorial/The_Box_Model) for positioning. The `width` and `height` attributes define the intrinsic size of the element, not the size at which they are displayed. Your button is apparently placed in a vertical box (not necessarily the actual [`vbox` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/vbox), rather any element with [`orient="vertical"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/orient)). By default, the [`align` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Attribute/align) of a box is assumed to have the value `stretch` - so a vertical box will always stretch the elements inside it horizontally:

```xml
<vbox>
  <!-- this button is stretched horizontally to match the width of its container -->
  <button label="Ok" width="16" height="16"/>
</vbox>
```

You can set the `align` attribute explicitly to avoid this:

```xml
<vbox align="center">
  <!-- this button is centered inside its container -->
  <button label="Ok" width="16" height="16"/>
</vbox>
```